# How to manually set : kendo-ui numerictextbox's currency

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-mvc

I have that numerictextbox which shows amount with currency. I wanna display my Model's currency but that numerictextbox always shows culture's currency. For exp. If I change website's language German then this textbox shows "€". How can I display my Model's currency instead of culture's currency? 
Or maybe is there a way to set numerictextbox's culture to currency's culture?

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox<decimal>()
    .Name("amount")
    .Min(Model.MinPrice)       
    .Value(Model.MinPrice)
    .Format(Strings.ResourceManager.GetString(Model.Currency.ToString()) + " #.00")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 104px;" })
)
```

Also when I view-source the page it shows that:

```
jQuery(function(){jQuery("#Amount").kendoNumericTextBox({"format":"$ #.00"});});
```

But in the page it shows "€"(current culture's currency) instead of $

Anyone has same problem this is working version:

```
<script>
    var currCulture = kendo.culture();
    currCulture.numberFormat.currency.symbol = '@Strings.ResourceManager.GetString(Model.Currency.ToString())';
</script>

@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox<decimal>()
     .Name("TicketOptions[" + i + "].Price")
     .Min(memberTicketOptions[i].MinPrice)
     .Value(memberTicketOptions[i].MinPrice)
     .Format(Strings.ResourceManager.GetString(Model.Currency.ToString()) + " #.00")
     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 104px;" })
 )
```

Comment: If the page shows `kendoNumericTextBox({"format":"$ #.00"})` are you sure that `Model.Currency.ToString()` is returning the correct value?

Comment: @OnaBai yes,i m sure

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would need to change the current currency smybol inside kendos culture, before initializing your controls:

```
var currCulture = kendo.culture();
//currCulture.numberFormat.currency.symbol = '¥';
//currCulture.numberFormat.currency.symbol = '€';
//currCulture.numberFormat.currency.symbol = '$';
currCulture.numberFormat.currency.symbol = '@Model.Currency.ToString()';

$("#amount").kendoNumericTextBox({
    format: "c",
    decimals: 3,
    culture: currCulture
});
```

This would then print your models currency symbol.

Comment: That s what i m looking for, works fine for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should define [`culture`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/numerictextbox/configuration/culture) at [`NumericTextBox`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/numerictextbox) level overwriting what you have defined at page level.

Remember that you need to include the localization file corresponding to the additional cultures that you want to support. You might have more than one.

Example include German and English(GB):

```
<!-- Include German -->
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/js/cultures/kendo.culture.de-DE.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include English/GB -->
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/js/cultures/kendo.culture.en-GB.min.js"></script>
```

Example usage multiple cultures:

```
  $("#deDE").kendoNumericTextBox({
    culture: "de-DE",
    value: 123.45,
    format: "c2"
  });
   $("#usUS").kendoNumericTextBox({
    culture: "us-US",
    value: 123.45,
    format: "c2"
  });
   $("#enGB").kendoNumericTextBox({
    culture: "en-GB",
    value: 123.45,
    format: "c2"
  });
```

Use format `cN` for *currency* where `N` is the number of decimal digits.

Following a snippet showing it.

```js
$("#deDE").kendoNumericTextBox({
  culture: "de-DE",
  value: 123.45,
  format: "c2"
});
$("#usUS").kendoNumericTextBox({
  culture: "us-US",
  value: 123.45,
  format: "c2"
});
$("#enGB").kendoNumericTextBox({
  culture: "en-GB",
  value: 123.45,
  format: "c2"
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/js/kendo.all.min.js" 0></script>

<!-- Extra culture files -->
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/js/cultures/kendo.culture.de-DE.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/js/cultures/kendo.culture.en-GB.min.js"></script>


<div>German<input id="deDE" /></div>
<div>USA<input id="usUS" /></div>
<div>GB<input id="enGB" /></div>
```

Comment: first thanks for your effort But my problem isn t about implementng cultures. I already done with this. I don t want that textbox displays current culture's currency. I want it dislays my Model's currency. User can use site in German language but I don t want to show currency Euro.

Comment: @bthn my answer allows you to define a `culture` at field level. You can use a different culture for each numeric text box. What you have to do is initialize `culture` depending the value on your model. Is this not feasible?